# List Contacts from a group from Zend GData

Tags: php, zend-framework, cakephp, gdata-api, google-contacts-api

and thanks for reading.

My problem is that I'm trying to get a list of contacts belonging to a group in GData using Zend_Gdata_Query.

Using

```
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Query('http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/?group=http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/xxx...xxx/base/XXX');
$feed = $gdata->getFeed($query);
```

give me an "Unknown authorization header".

```
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Query('http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/');
$query->setParam('group', 'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/XXX...XXX/base/XXX');
$feed = $gdata->getFeed($query);
```

is the same.

Obviously without that parameter I get all the contacts.

I already tried the first method with the parameter in the URL with a modified Extension to CakePHP core HttpSocket and it was working. So I suppose the problem is with Zend stripping out parameters from the url but I had no luck looking at the libraries.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Same problem when using
    $query->setParam('max-results', '10');
or
    $query->setMaxResults(10);

So I think the problem is on how I used the Zend Library...

Answer (score 3):

```
$query->setParam('group', 'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/myemail%40gmail.com/base/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxx = group ID

Answer (score 1):

As above the max-results also works if you add it to the query string like so:
http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=1000

Note that even in the google documentation the only way of getting ALL results is by 'setting a high number' for the number of results returned. So you can never explicitly specify 'ALL'

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using 3-legged OAuth. Then you need to add next line before getFeed() called:
$gdata->getHttpClient()->setRequestScheme(Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_QUERYSTRING);
It will solve "Unknown authorization header" error.

For me using
$query->setParam('group', 'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/XXX...XXX/base/XXX');
returns another error: "Invalid value for group parameter: XXXXXXXXXX" and I still dunno how to fix it :(

Comment: Your solution worked (I set a setMaxResults(10))!
Many thanks!
As you I need to pull a group too: I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Same problem here with setParam('group', ... ).

Comment: A workaround is putting the query param in the URL:
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Query('http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?group=http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/foo@gmail.com/base/s0mething');